# How to implement this pattern in Lua with Cocos2d-x

Tags: lua, cocos2d-x

I wanna call `GameScene` `setSpecificSquare` function in `Square`, it will occur 'attempt to index field 'squares' error.

In my understanding, `require("GameScene")` in `onTouchEnded(touch event)` do not get the last variable of `GameScene`, it has not been constructed, so it does not have `squares` attribute.

How to call `GameScene` static function `setSpecificSquare` in `Square`? Or in other word, how to get the last `GameScene` so I can set `self.squares` table?

Thanks in advanced!!  :)

**Square.lua**

```
require "Cocos2d"
require "Cocos2dConstants"

        local Square = class("Square",function()
            return cc.Node:create()
        end)

        function Square.create()

            local square = Square.new()

            return square
        end

        function Square:ctor()
            self.bg = cc.Sprite:create("square_bg.png")
            self:addChild(self.bg)
            self.isHighlight = true
            local function onTouchEnded(touch,event)
              --occur error here
              require("GameScene"):setSpecificSquare()
            end
        end

return Square
```

**GameScene.lua**

```
require "Cocos2d"
require "Cocos2dConstants"

local GameScene = class("GameScene",function()
    return cc.Scene:create()
end)

function GameScene.create()
    local scene = GameScene.new()
    return scene
end


function GameScene:ctor()
    self.visibleSize = cc.Director:getInstance():getVisibleSize()
    self.x = cc.Director:getInstance():getVisibleOrigin().x
    self.y = cc.Director:getInstance():getVisibleOrigin().y

    self.squares = {}
    for i=0, 5 do
        self.squares[i] = {}    -- create a new row
        for j=0, 5 do
            self.squares[i][j] = nil
        end
    end
    --add layer
    self.bombLayer = cc.Layer:create()
    self:addChild(self.bombLayer)

    --add squares
    self:addSquares()
end

function GameScene:addSquares()

    for i=0,5 do
        for j=0,5 do
            local square = require("src/Square"):create()
            square:setPosition(0+j*70,0+i*70)

            self.bombLayer:addChild(square)

            self.squares[i][j] = square

        end
    end

end

function GameScene:setSpecificSquare()
--can not access self.square here, occur attempt to index field 'squares' error
self.square[0][0].isHighLight
end

return GameScene
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `self.squares = {}` out of `ctor` function, or call `ctor` function before calling `addSquares`, or you can just call this function inside `addsquares`.

The recommended method is moving it out of function and creating it on creation of your `GameScene` object:

```
require "Cocos2d"
require "Cocos2dConstants"

local GameScene = class("GameScene",function()
    return cc.Scene:create()
end)

function GameScene.create()
    local scene = GameScene.new()
    return scene
end

GameScene.squares = {}

...
```